# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] - Rails 7 - Action UPDATE

Tags: crud, ruby-on-rails-7

When I try to update a product it shows the error

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/despensa")

I don't know what i did wrong

This is my archives:

Controller:

```
  def edit
        id = params[:id]
        @produto = Produto.find(id)
        @corredors = Corredor.all
        render :new
    end

    def update
        id = params[:id]
        @produto = Produto.find(id)
        valores = params.require(:produto).permit(:nome, :quantidade, :unidade_de_medida, :corredor_id)
        if @produto.update valores
            flash[:notice] = "Produto atualizado"
            redirect_to despensa_index_path
        else
            @corredors = Corredor.all
            render :new
        end
    end
```

Routes:

```
corredors_path  GET /corredors(.:format)    
corredors#index

POST    /corredors(.:format)    
corredors#create

new_corredor_path   GET /corredors/new(.:format)    
corredors#new

edit_corredor_path  GET /corredors/:id/edit(.:format)   
corredors#edit

corredor_path   GET /corredors/:id(.:format)    
corredors#show

PATCH   /corredors/:id(.:format)    
corredors#update

PUT /corredors/:id(.:format)    
corredors#update

DELETE  /corredors/:id(.:format)    
corredors#destroy

busca_despensa_path GET /despensa/busca(.:format)   
despensa#busca

despensa_index_path GET /despensa(.:format) 
despensa#index

POST    /despensa(.:format) 
despensa#create

new_despensa_path   GET /despensa/new(.:format) 
despensa#new

edit_despensa_path  GET /despensa/:id/edit(.:format)    
despensa#edit

despensa_path   PATCH   /despensa/:id(.:format) 
despensa#update

PUT /despensa/:id(.:format) 
despensa#update

DELETE  /despensa/:id(.:format) 
despensa#destroy

root_path   GET /   
home#index
```

Form:

```
<%@produto.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
   <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2" role="alert">
        <%= msg %>
    </div>
<%end%>


<%= form_for(@produto, url: despensa_index_path) do |form|%>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= form.label :nome %>
                <%= form.text_field :nome, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= form.label :quantidade %>
                <%= form.number_field :quantidade, step:0.01, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= form.label :unidade_de_medida %>
                <%= form.text_field :unidade_de_medida, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= form.label :corredor %>
                <%= form.collection_select :corredor_id, @corredors, :id, :nome, {}, class:"form-control" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <%= form.submit "Adicionar produto", class: "btn btn-primary mt-3"%>

<% end %>
```

Maybe is something wrong with the form, but i dont know. It works when i try to edit, but when i save it goes to the error.

Comment: The problem here is that i named my model 'produto' and the controller and views 'despensa'.

Answer (score 0):

`/despensa` is not available

Your route defines `despensa` as `resources` INSIDE `corredors`.

So the path should be called something like `corredors_despensa_path` and not `despensa_path` check your routes using `rails routes`.

Side note: you have to be careful naming stuff, you are using a singular name for a plural definition (despensa instead of despensas). If you can, try to write down the routes and most of the code in English, even if you are a non-native speaker.

Comment: No.... it did not work :( 
I dont know how to solve. But thank u for the tip, i'll do that in the next project

Comment: Maybe if you remove the url parameter, form_for will determine by itself the correct route and add the correct method to it.